# How to programatically change keyboard language to Arabic?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on an Android app that needs to take input in Arabic whenever the User taps on an EditText view. So how do I change the keyboard language programatically or ask the User to do so?
I conducted extensive research and found out that it can be done via:
a) creating a custom Arabic keyboard,
b) using the IME manager to prompt the user to change input method by calling showInputMethodPicker(),
c) using the IME manager to change input method by calling setInputMethod.

of these, (c) is only workable for System apps, and (a) requires a lot of time (which I currently don't have), and (b) requires the user to manually enable it.

Is there absolutely ANY simple and workable way to accomplish this? Any external API that I could use or anything at all?

Comment: do you want your application language to be Arabic ?

Comment: No, that'll be English. Only the keyboard language has to be Arabic.

Comment: for whole project or you want to manipulate it ?

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/996415/ceate-custom-arabic-keyboard-for-android

Above link can help you.For getting above required feature you need to make custom keyboard Arabic then open that keyboard when you type in edit text.

Comment: Yep, I thought the same. Anyway, thank you for the url, and I hope it helps!

Comment: yes it will be done like this , another approach might not be available.